# В мобильном приложении убрать увеличение шрифта, если в телефоне это включено

Tags: android, ios, ionic

Когда в настройках телефона включаешь увеличение текста или размер отображения, то в приложение некоторые блоки ломаются, как сделать, что бы приложение игнорировало эту функцию в телефоне (IOS, Android)?

Comment: Откуда вообще появляется желание «сделать плохо» вместо «сделать правильно»?

Comment: Что значит плохо и что значит правильно? В некоторых приложениях не нужна эта функция, в том числе я говорю про своё, поэтому и задался этим вопросом

Comment: можно вместо "sp" использовать "dp", тогда изменение размера шрифта в телефоне не повлияет на его размер в приложении, но повлечет за собой другие проблемы)

Comment: А вы не думали, что если пользователь увеличивает размер шрифта, то это не просто так? И почему вы думаете, что в некоторых приложениях эта функция не нужна?

Comment: @Эникейщик За чем отговаривать меня в моем вопросе?) Где-то нужен, где-то требуется это убрать, в чем проблема?  В большой части игр на телефоне, отключают эту функцию внутри игры